# How to findur Bitcoins and wallet

Tags: wallet, bitcoind

lababyblue32@yahoo.com
Amanda glenn
I'm new to this got an email stating I needed withdrawal my cash I made off Bitcoin bonus so I did but I don't know where it went I need to know how to receive it or recover it or if I even got anything

Comment: This all just sounds like a scam to me. Did you expect this email? Have you owned any bitcoin before?

Comment: Welcome to bitcoin.stackexchange.com. It looks to me like a scam. See [this other similar question about "Bitcoin Bonus"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/115682/13866)